# Invalid logger interface org.hibernate.internal.EntityManagerMessageLogger

Tags: java, jpa, logging, dependencies

I am doing JPA without persistence.xml (without Spring Boot) and instead used the PersistenceUnitInfo to create the entity manager. When running the application from my IDE, there are no errors, but it logs sensitive persistence unit information. I've struggled to disable the logging.

It gets worse, when I run it from the command line, I get the following:

[image]

Kindly assist, I've lost quite a few hours to this one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you encounter is a classloading issue during initialization of your EntityManager on your JBoss application environement.

Disabling the logging will not fix this error, but hide it. Check your deployment classpath, and your JDK version. And verify that all required hibernate libraries are present. You can check which libraries you need on the classpath by looking at the dependencies on a site such as mvnRepository (example: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.0.2.Final).

Are you using a dependency manager, such as Maven or Gradle?

Comment: This was in a standalone jar. I wasn't deploying it to JBoss. I gave up and moved to Spring and it worked like a charm

Comment: I see, I am happy you solved your issue!
If you still have the fat-jar: you can open it up and check the included libraries to check whether or not the libraries (hibernate-core, and and it's required logging dependency) were present in your bundle.
If you say you were not explicitly using Jboss/Wildfly, I find it curious how the `jboss` namespace ended up in your logging stack.

also: Consider closing your question, if it is no longer relevant and you are not planning on trying the approach again :)